# A confusion about my solution

Tags: probability

A caterpillar is moving on the edges of a tetrahedron $ABCD$ on whose top there is glue. In a unit of time the caterpillar goes from any vertex (except D) to any other vertex with the same probability $1/3$. Suppose the caterpillar at time $t=0$ is on $A$.

(a) Pr(The caterpillar finally gets stuck)

(b) Pr(The caterpillar finally gets stuck coming from B)

What I did :
See if we do first one and it has probability $p$ then the second one has probability $p/3$ due to symmetry. So we try to find the first one. Let us denote $p_n=\Pr($there are $n$ vertices in between the time the insect reaches D from A $:=A_n)$. Now $p_0=1/3$. We induct
$P(A_n)=P(A_n|A \rightarrow B)P(A\rightarrow B)+P(A_n|A \rightarrow C)P(A\rightarrow C)=1/3p_{n-1}+1/3p_{n-1}=\dfrac{2p_{n-1}}{3}$

Now our required probability is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p_n=1$. This seems correct to me but the answer of $1$ makes me believe I am wrong. Can someone help me out? If I am wrong then please give me the right solution. Thanks.

Comment: Let $p$ be the probability that the caterpillar gets stuck at some point. The probability that it gets stuck after the first move is $\frac{1}{3}$, and if it doesn't get stuck after the first move, it is in the exact same situation as it was before the move, so the probability that it gets stuck, but not immediately is $\frac{2}{3}\cdot p$. Hence $p = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\cdot p$, and thus $p = 1$. Also, the probability that it isn't stuck after $n$ moves is $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

It's *almost certain* that the caterpillar will get stuck if this scenario continues long enough; it's only a question of when it makes the terminal move, and from where.

While it might seem intuitive that there is an equal chance that the caterpillar can approach $D$ from each of the three other vertices, the situation is *not* actually symmetrical.   We must consider the initial state.

At $t=0$ the caterpillar starts at node $A$.   There is a $1/3$ chance of *immediately* crawling to node $D$, and a $1/3$ chance each of crawling to node $B$ or $C$.   From either $B$ or $C$ it can continue to move back and forth between these nodes an indefinite amount of times until it eventually either returns to node $A$ or moves off to node $D$ with equal chance.

So the probability that it will ultimately move to $D$ from node $A$ is:

$$\mathsf P(A) = \frac 1 3 + \frac 2 3 \frac 1 2 \mathsf P(A)
\\ \therefore \mathsf P(A) = \frac 1 2$$

Now at time $t=1$ it will either be stuck at node $D$, or else at either node $B$ or $C$ with equal chance.   *Now* we can use symmetry to state that the *conditional probability* that the caterpillar moves to $D$ from $B$ *when given* that it does not do so from $A$ is: $1/2$

$$\mathsf P(B\mid\neg A) = \frac 12 \\ \mathsf P(B) = \mathsf P(B\mid \neg A)\mathsf P(\neg A) + \underbrace{\mathsf P(B\mid A)}_{0}\mathsf P(A) \implies \mathsf P(B) = \frac 1 4$$

Likewise for $C$. So thus:$$\mathsf P(A) = \frac 1 2, \mathsf P(B) = \frac 1 4, \mathsf P(C) = \frac 1 4$$

---

Alternatively.

At $t=0$ the caterpillar is not on node $B$.  It can move back and forth between nodes $A$ and $C$ an indefinite number of times until it eventually moves to either node $D$ or $B$ with an equal chance.  Once at node $B$ it may either move to node $D$ or return to either node $A$ or $C$.

Thus the probability of ultimately moving to $D$ from $B$ is:
$$\mathsf P(B) = \frac 12 \left(\frac 1 3 + \frac 2 3 \mathsf P(B)\right) \\ \therefore \mathsf P(B) = \frac 1 4$$

Since a symmetrical argument can be made for the probability of ultimately moving to $D$ from node $C$, $\mathsf P(C)=\mathsf P(B) = \frac 1 4$, and hence $\mathsf P(A) = 1 -\mathsf P(B\cup C) = \frac 1 2$